# 2 card requests at once clash royale

Tags: clash-royale

I requested a epic card and no one in my clan has given me one yet and 7 hours later I can request another card. THE 1st request is still up, so if I request my 2nd card will the 1st one be deleted?

Comment: Good question.  Couldn't find an answer myself.  Just my two cents... play it safe and don't request until your old request is fulfilled or buried under 100 clan messages.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same situation just now and since I didn't see the answer I went ahead and made the request so that I could give you guys the answer. It appears that you can only have one request in the clan chat at once, as when I made the second request my original request disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

> TL:DR version: The previous request will gets deleted automatically when you make
>   your other request of the day.

Last Sunday I noticed this, as we all know how **Executioner** is ruling the game, so many of my clan members may be 12 or 13 of them requested for him only 4 requests got filled other all went in vain.

As per the chat space the older messages and friendly battles will be automatically gets cleared but card requests will be stayed on top, so when the members who requested Executioner requested for other card after 7 hours and all the Epic card request got deleted automatically.

Answer (score 0):

When you request for cards the card request stays up until you request cards again or until the max cards that you can get is filled. This not only for Epic cards but also for the rest of the cards.